# Pythonic / itertools way to go through a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

```
def reportCSV(t):
    ret = ''
    for ev in t:
        for p in t[ev]:
            for w in t[ev][p]:
                ret += ','.join((ev, p, w, t[ev][p][w])) + '\n'
    return ret
```

What is a more pythonic way to do this, e.g. using itertools or the like?

In this case I'm just writing it out to a CSV file. 
t is a dict
t[ev] is a dict
t[ev][p] is a dict
t[ev][p][w] is a float

I'm not sure how I'd use itertools.product in this case.

Comment: `for ev in t.keys()` is the same as `for ev in t`

Comment: I'm a little confused, what is the structure of your dict?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with this dict? what is the result? it seems like you want to recursively devle into a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries... etc.etc... but what is your end-goal? there might be a better way. show your data structure, your input and expected output. its hard to help you with this question. if you look only for a way to recursively iterate through dicts, its simple, but you must ask the right questions.

Comment: Pythonic way would be to ditch `.keys()` (as pointed out above + more efficient) and use standard `csv` module. And I'm not sure `itertools.product` or smth going to cut it since you have a dependency. Looks complicated just because of your data structure being complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have could be rewritten as:

```
def reportCSV(t):
    result = []
    for t_key, t_value in t.iteritems():
        for p_key, p_value in t_value.iteritems():
            for w_key, w_value in p_value.iteritems():
                row_data = t_key, p_key, w_key, w_value
                result.append(','.join(row_data))
    return '\n'.join(result)
```

This will be faster since it joins strings together instead of performing a number of concatenations, and more efficient because it uses `iteritems()` which removes the need to do any extra dictionary lookups or create intermediary lists.

Comment: yes, this would be the correct approach in this case, though if you were doing this type of process many times, a helper function that extracts (keyA, keyB, keyC, value) would be simple to write and make the code much more readable. if you wanted to have dynamic depth, then a recursive helper function would be a must.